# Most appropriate test for identifying if one group has significantly higher variance in its samples, than another?

Tags: statistics, variance

I am conducting analyses on fMRI (neural) data. There are two brain regions of focus, region1 and region2. For each region, there are 5 subjects worth of neural data (5 samples). Each sample is shaped as 72 x 79 x 95 x 79 x 4, or collapsible to 79 x 95 x 79 x 288.

**I want to establish whether there is higher variance in the data between subjects in region1, than there is variance between subjects in region2**.

What statistical test would you recommend to assess this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's fMRI data, let us assume your samples are independent between subjects, normally distributed, and equal variance.

**If the regions are independent**, that is, data for region 1 was collected from 5 subjects and data for region 2 was collected from 5 *unrelated* subjects, then the canonical answer is to use an F-test for equality of variances ([link1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances), [link2](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda359.htm)).

**If the regions are dependent**, where the data was collected in 5 subjects only, and then region1 and region2 extracted from the same 5 subjects, then you have a few options. A popular solution is the [Pitman-Morgan test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PairedData/versions/0.9.1/topics/pitman.morgan.test) for variance in paired samples. Various modifications have been proposed, of which [Wilcox (2015)](https://jsdajournal.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40488-015-0030-z) does a good job at controlling for Type I error.

Comment: Hi Ivan
Thank you so much for taking the time do answer. The regions are indeed dependent. The neural data for both regions is collected form the same 5 subjects. I am not sure whether the data is normally distributed yet. The histogram indicates yes, the shapiro test indicates no.  Is it possible to use the pitman-morgan test to show not just that they have unequal vairance, but that one has higher variance than the other group?
Thanks again for your advice!

Comment: For fMRI data, it is generally assumed the time-varying signal is normally distributed. That is one of the requirements for GLM models, so if you are using FSL FEAT, SPM, etc. then you are already making that assumption!
As for your second question - by definition, if two groups have unequal variance, one has higher variance than the other :) The Pitman-Morgan test looks a lot like a Student's T-test - you get a t-value, where the sign (+/-) tells you which group has the larger variance. Have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90A0zRqTH4k